# Redis Server in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, redis-server

I have installed Redis-server using command sudo apt install redis-server and it's showing the output on command redis-cli ping but when I see the status it is showing error message.

```
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-07-26 12:45:55 UTC; 20min ago
       Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
             man:redis-server(1)
    Process: 925832 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 925834 (redis-server)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 9513)
     Memory: 2.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/redis-server.service
             └─925834 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379

Jul 26 12:45:55 probity-admin systemd[1]: Starting Advanced key-value store...
Jul 26 12:45:55 probity-admin systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Can't open PID file /run/redis/redis-server.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
Jul 26 12:45:55 probity-admin systemd[1]: Started Advanced key-value store.
```

I checked and PID file is already there and config file is also showing the same path. Can someone let me know when is the issue?

Comment: I resolved it myself. The issue was with kombu version installed with celery. I updated celery and redis version and now things are working properly.